# Spring Kafka doesn't autocreate topics

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using `spring-kafka` and I want it to auto create my topics on startup. I've configured it by adding `@Bean NewTopic` in my configuration class. This however doesn't seem to execute because earlier, from what I see in logs, `NetworkClient` from `apache-kafka` is  "Sending METADATA request", then the response says:

`topics=[MetadataResponseTopic(errorCode=3`
and
`Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {my.topic.name=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}`

then this repeats for 60 seconds (max.block.ms) and finally stops the whole app, because Spring fails to initialize all the beans, because of this missing topic.
It seems that `NewTopic` bean doesn't get a chance to be called and do its job.

Anyone knows what's wrong?

Can I in any way control order of execution of things here, so that `NewTopic` is called (and actual topic created) when spring initializes beans but before any of them starts doing their job (trying to send something to that not-yet existing topic)

Comment: You probably try to publish record to that topic too early. See if you can move that logic a bit later in the application phase.

Comment: thanks @ArtemBilan - yes, that was actually the case - one of spring beans was doing something while initializing that already caused an attempt of interaction with Kafka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as @Artem suggested, the problem was that one of my Spring beans during initialization was already executing some code which involved interaction with Kafka, hence - spring didn't fully initialize beans because it crashed before `NewTopic` was used